# Can slimes spawn on glass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can slime spawn on glass? My idea is to have a fully transparent slime farm (not automatic) so I can see the slime flapping around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, slimes follow spawning mechanics of regular mobs, except they can spawn with a higher light level in slime chunks. Regular mobs won't spawn on glass, or stained glass, so slimes will not either.

Comment: I once experimented this hard way. We found slime chunk and wanted to do big farm , so we made glass floors so we can see on which floor the slime spawned...and yes, it was epic fail, no slime spawned ever......but slime chunks are irrelevant since slimes spawn regularly in swamps now.

Comment: I'm doing it 1. for fun and 2. for convenience to have slime near my base when I need some more slimeballs.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík slime chunks are still highly relevant for farms. Since they ignore the light level in the slime chunks, you can get exclusively slimes spawning there.

Comment: Actually, the requirement for a solid surface and space requirements are just about the only spawning rules for hostile mobs that slimes *do* follow. The rules are similar in swamps, but there's a y-level limit (51-69) and strange failure chances and moon-phase relations. In slime chunks, they do their own thing altogether.